# Do I need to re-draw the entire canvas every frame?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, game-physics

For example, if I have a plain canvas, with the ground and a sun/moon on it, and then every frame I re-draw the character (so it can be moved using arrow keys) do I need to re-draw everything, or can I keep the background static and just move (by removing/re-drawing) the character sprite/image?

Answer (score 1):

You could layer two `<canvas>` elements on top of one another.  Otherwise, yes, you would need to redraw the entire area that has changed.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best solution

Answer (score 1):

There are no different layers inside a canvas tag, so in order to remove only a certain part of your image you'd need to draw something upon it. If you have an image background behind it this can become complicated.

In your case I would definitely redraw it at a certain rate using `setInterval` or use more than one `canvas` element to keep the layers separated.